# Mysql - fetch data and total rows from multiple tables having same structure

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to fetch data from multiple tables having same data structure but different data in it, without using "UNION"....
Also I want to fetch total number of records like using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS...

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use union. I believe you could merge the all the table to one.
For more details and pros and cons, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/merge-storage-engine.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html